# PowerShell Get request with body

Tags: powershell, rest, python-requests, mlflow

I am trying [this api endpoint](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#search-modelversions).
I can call this in python, no problem, like the below

```
get_model_versions={
    "filter":"name='model_name'",
    "order_by":["version DESC"],
    "max_results":1
}

init_get = requests.get("baseurl/api/2.0/preview/mlflow/model-versions/search",headers=header_read,json=get_model_versions)
```

However, I just can't seem to find a way to make it work in Powershell.

First the powershell "get" Invoke-RestMethod does not accept a body

and then I can't seem to find a way to append it in Powershell as a query string.

I have tried (among other failed attempts), the following

```
$get_model_versions=([PSCustomObject]@{
  filter = "name=`'model_name`'"
  order_by = @("version desc")
} | ConvertTo-Json)

$resp=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $searchuri -Headers $auth -Method Get -Body $get_model_versions
```

But that gives me an error that body can't be used with a get method

trying to append it as a query string (like if I even just keep the name filter and remove the others), also fails

```
$searchuri= "baseurl/api/2.0/preview/mlflow/model-versions/search?filter=""name==model_name"""

$resp=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $searchuri -Headers $auth -Method Get
```

fails with

```
{"error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"Unsupported filter query : `\"name==model_name\"`. Unsupported operator."}
```

How can I mimic the same behaviour in Powershell, as I do in Python?

EDIT 1: I did try to encode the query param (maybe I did it wrong), but here's how my failed attempt looked like

```
$encodedvalue = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("`"name='model_name'`"")
$searchuri= "baseurl/api/2.0/preview/mlflow/model-versions/search?filter=$encodedvalue"

$resp=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $searchuri -Headers $auth -Method Get
```

But that too gives me

```
"Unsupported filter query : `\"name='model_name'\"`. Unsupported operator."
```

I have also tried it successfully in Postman by passing a raw json body (the same as python) and when I look at the generated PowerShell code in Postman I see this

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer token")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$body = "{
`n    `"filter`":`"name='model_name'`",
`n    `"order_by`":[`"version DESC`"],
`n    `"max_results`":1
`n}
`n"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'baseurl/api/2.0/preview/mlflow/model-versions/search' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

But of course that fails (if you copy that in an powershell editor and run it

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type
```

Comment: try `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'baseurl/api/2.0/preview/mlflow/model-versions/search?filter=%22name%3d%27my-model-name%27%22%26max_results%3d1' -Method Get`

Comment: @Avshalom: Thanks for this but I get an error `{"error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"Unsupported filter query : `\"name='my-model-name'\"&max_results=1`. Expected binary operations."} `

Comment: I did try encoding earlier btw , something like `$encodedvalue = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("`"name='model_name'`"")` and then passing it for the filter param, but that too failed. I will update my question with that attempt as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after struggling for a long time, I found the answer !

The crux is in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2).
Especially this section

[image]

So, if you want to pass on a body for your "get" method in powershell, pass it as a hashtable.

So, finally the answer is

```
$query=@{"filter"="name='model_name'";"order_by"=@("version DESC"); "max_results"=1};
$searchuri="baseurl/api/2.0/preview/mlflow/model-versions/search"

$resp=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $searchuri -Headers $auth -Method Get -Body $query
```

Hope this helps someone looking for something similar.

Comment: Nice; note that this mirrors your Python solution, given that PowerShell's (.NET's) equivalent of Python's `dict` data type is a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables). As for your attempts to construct a query string directly: at least one potential problem is trying to include `"` chars.

Comment: Yeah , I know. The api specifically mentioned it. But, I tried all possible combinations (with, without) , but it just wouldn’t work with query strings (with or without). I would like to know however, how the hashtable is actually added as a query string (which the doc specifies). I could inspect Fiddler (proxy) logs.

Comment: You can use the `-Verbose` switch to see the resulting query string constructed from a `-Body` argument; e.g.: `Invoke-RestMethod 'https://postman-echo.com/get' -Body @{ foo1='bar 1'; foo2='bar+2' } -Verbose`